# How can I get a .pdf's article abstract into my C++ program

Tags: c++, pdf

I was searching for some ways to read `.pdf` files and I wasn't able to get anything from it, I would probably need a library but all the options I found is very confusing and hard to deal with.

I was wondering which way would be the best way for me to do this task, which is to search through the `.pdf` and get the content in the Abstract section of it. (which is text)

Comment: would you happen to know one that is simply to use?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and cheapest is using an open source library which is popular and known to other programmers.

Before trying to write your own PDF reader from scratch, take look at these:

Parsing:

- [PoDoFo](http://podofo.sourceforge.net/about.html)

> The PoDoFo library is a free, portable C++ library which includes
>   classes to parse PDF files and modify their contents into memory. The
>   changes can be written back to disk easily. The parser can also be
>   used to extract information from a PDF file (for example the parser
>   could be used in a PDF viewer). Besides parsing PoDoFo includes also
>   very simple classes to create your own PDF files. All classes are
>   documented so it is easy to start writing your own application using
>   PoDoFo.
>   
>   Generating:

- [LibHaru](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libharu/)

  > Haru is a free, cross platform, open-sourced software library for
  >   generating PDF written in ANSI-C. It can work as both a static-library
  >   (.a, .lib) and a shared-library (.so, .dll).
- [panda](http://sourceforge.net/projects/panda/)

  > A PDF generation API written in C

Comment: for a DIY solution [Adobe's PDF spec from 2006](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#cite_note-pdf-ref-1.7-1) might be useful, considering the pricing of ISO standards. re libraries, possibly there's a useful one as part of Open Office. unless Open Office uses one of the above

Comment: I believe PoDoFo is currently the best one for me, still I find it kind of hard to use new libraries without much of examples, I think the podofo tool I wanted is the: podofotxtextract, but I dont know how to use it, would you by any chance have examples of it?